# What was the first video game console controller with ANALOG trigger buttons?

Tags: controllers, gaming-history

I want to emphasize the word "ANALOG" so that you understand that i am not referring to digital trigger buttons

I want to know what was the first controller with analog trigger buttons, not digital trigger buttons

Answer (score 4):

Earliest I can think of is the 3D Control Pad for the Sega Saturn, released in July 1996. When the switch on the bottom face is set to O (for analog), the triggers (and directional pad) can be polled for analog values. When the switch is set to +, those inputs are polled for digital/binary values like on the stock Saturn pad.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_controllers) on wikipedia, the earliest controller listing analog triggers is the 1998 Dreamcast controller.